# browser text editor

Tags: javascript, json, editor, text-editor

Any idea about the library used to achieve this JSON editor?
[image: JSON Editor Online]

It's available in http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html.
You can clearly see that it's checking the syntax & displaying an error when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) to me . It has syntax highlighting and checking also supports a lot of languages.

**Edit:**
Inspecting the site you gave you can see that they are using Ace Editor.
[image: screenshot of the website http://schemaform.io/ sources where we can see it ace-editor is used]

Comment: It can be used with javascript?

Comment: Yes , its a JS library that you can include in your project and use it . Its quite simple to include and init.